# Native NuGet packages in Windows Store app

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, nuget, libraries

I have a library written in C++ and Windows Store/Windows Phone apps written in C#. I want to pack my C++ libs in a NuGet package, which will be architecture-specific (x86, x64, ARM etc.) and to add it into my Windows Store/Windows Phone apps. What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now NuGet does not officially support it yet. But you can probably use the workaround of msbuild .target files to achieve it.

For more please refer to this issue - https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/679.